# Net scan Out Level server Hetzner

Tags: linux, server, vpn, vps, openvpn

I have VPS server Linux and I install OPEN VPN on it
I receive this message [NetscanOutLevel: Netscan detected] from Hetzner data center
how to fix net scan on ubuntu 20.04 VPS?

Answer (score 0):

```
how to fix net scan on ubuntu 20.04 VPS?
```

By moving to another host.

If you are on Hetzner and you just ping the wrong IP, they will say you are doing a "netscan" and will block your server.

They have many lists of IPs from sketchy sources, and if your server communicated with one of these IPs in any way, Hetzner will block your server.

Answer (score 0):

First off your 20.04 is a bit old. You might want to install 22.04 at least. 20.04 still has security upgrades of course, but your OpenVPN Version might be a bit old there.

Secondly in my experience (hosting several 100s of Servers on Hetzner.de), when they send you this email about the portscans, your server usually got hacked somehow. They will usually block the server if you dont respond to that email with "sorry, it was XYZ, i'll fix it right now".

Do you have a (simple) password for the root Account with passwords enabled in SSH? ;) Maybe there actually is someone on your box running portscans.

If you are *SURE* it wasnt you running `nmap` or so, then I'd to consider the box compromised and reinstall it.